# "in a known concentration" vs. "at a known concentration"

Tags: difference

> Prepare samples containing Host Cell Protein **in a known concentration**.

I wrote this, but then looked up Google Ngram:

[image]

"At a known concentration" is more prevalent.

In Google Books, I found [this example](https://books.google.ru/books?id=YP4IBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA605&dq=%22at%20a%20known%20concentration%22&hl=ru&pg=PA605#v=onepage&q=%22at%20a%20known%20concentration%22&f=false):

> Calibration Gas means a gas standard containing Hg0 or HgCl2 **at a known concentration** that is produced and certified in accordance with an EPA traceability protocol for certification of Hg calibration standards.

Would **in a known concentration** in my sentence be wrong? If not, what is the difference between the two expressions?

Comment: **at** is not wrong.  It just has a different meaning.  When the samples have been prepared so that the protein is in a known concentration, we can state that the concentration level of the protein is at a known concentration.

Comment: Remember from the "in a circular motion" vs "with a circular motion" question that "in" refers to state, so "in" is fine here. The protein sample is "in" a concentration. "At" would refer to the identification of the concentration level, not to the concentration of the protein sample per se.

Comment: **In** is existential. **At** is epistemological.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to say, your situation can be described

> Prepare samples containing Host Cell Protein **to** a known concentration.
>   *you need to make samples to have a desired concentration of Host Cell Protein*
>
> Prepare samples containing Host Cell Protein **at** a known concentration.
>   *the original concentration of Host Cell Protein used to make the samples is known (before dilution).*
>
> Prepare samples containing Host Cell Protein **in** a known *(reagent)* concentration.
>   *cell protein samples were made using a prespecified reagent concentration*